# How can we show that $2^3+1^3+3^3+4^3+\cdots+L_n^3={L_nL_{n+1}^2+5(-1)^n[L_{n-1}+2(-1)^n]+9\over 2}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations, fibonacci-numbers

In my recent [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2069429/show-that-s-l-l-n2l-n1-l-1l-2l-3-l-2l-3l-4-cdots-l-n-2l-n-1l-n-n) I was intended to asked this question

$...,3,-1,2,1,3,4,7,...$ for $n=...,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4,...$; It is the [Lucas numbers](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas_number)

Let the sum of the cube of Lucas series be $S_L$

$S_L=2^3+1^3+3^3+4^3+\cdots+L_n^3$,

show that it has a closed form $$S_L={L_nL_{n+1}^2+5(-1)^n[L_{n-1}+2(-1)^n]+9\over 2}$$

I try: I can't think  of any simple identities to use.

This is the only one might have some sort of link to it,

$L_{n+1}^3+L_{n+2}^3={L_{n+3}\over 2}(L_n^2+L_{n+1}^2+L_{n+2}^2)$

$2^2+1^2+3^2+\cdots+L_n^2=L_nL_{n+1}+2$

Any further hints?

Comment: With Lucas numbers $ L_0=2, L_1=1,$..... we have $L_n=A^n+B^n$ where $A=(1+\sqrt 5 )/2$ and $B=(1-\sqrt 5)/2=-1/A. $  So $L_0+...+L_n$ is the sum of a pair of geometric series,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer uses that $$L_n^2-L_{n-1}L_{n+1}=5(-1)^n\tag1$$
whose proof can be seen at the end of this answer.

Using $(1)$, we get
$$\begin{align}&{L_nL_{n+1}^2+5(-1)^n[L_{n-1}+2(-1)^n]+9\over 2}\\\\&=\frac{L_nL_{n+1}^2+5(-1)^nL_{n-1}+10(-1)^{2n}+9}{2}\\\\&=\frac{L_nL_{n+1}^2+(L_n^2-L_{n-1}L_{n+1})L_{n-1}+10+9}{2}\\\\&=\frac{L_nL_{n+1}^2-L_{n-1}^2L_{n+1}+L_{n-1}L_n^2+19}{2}\end{align}$$
So, this answer proves by induction that
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n}L_k^3=\frac{L_nL_{n+1}^2-L_{n-1}^2L_{n+1}+L_{n-1}L_n^2+19}{2}$$

It holds for $n=0$.

Supposing that it holds for some $n\ (\ge 0)$ gives that
$$\begin{align}\sum_{k=0}^{n+1}L_k^3&=L_{n+1}^3+\sum_{k=0}^{n}L_k^3\\\\&=L_{n+1}^3+\frac{L_nL_{n+1}^2-L_{n-1}^2L_{n+1}+L_{n-1}L_n^2+19}{2}\\\\&=L_{n+1}^3+\frac{L_nL_{n+1}^2-(L_{n+1}-L_n)^2L_{n+1}+(L_{n+1}-L_n)L_n^2+19}{2}\\\\&=\frac{L_{n+1}^3+2L_nL_{n+1}^2+L_n^2L_{n+1}-L_n^3-L_n^2L_{n+1}+L_nL_{n+1}^2+19}{2}\\\\&=\frac{L_{n+1}(L_{n+1}+L_n)^2-L_n^2(L_n+L_{n+1})+L_nL_{n+1}^2+19}{2}\\\\&=\frac{L_{n+1}L_{n+2}^2-L_n^2L_{n+2}+L_nL_{n+1}^2+19}{2}\qquad\blacksquare\end{align}$$

---

Let us prove $(1)$ by induction.

It holds for $n=0$.

Supposing that it holds for some $n\ (\ge 0)$ gives that
$$\begin{align}5(-1)^{n+1}&=5(-1)^n\cdot (-1)\\\\&=-(L_n^2-L_{n-1}L_{n+1})\\\\&=-L_n^2+L_{n-1}(L_{n-1}+L_n)\\\\&=-L_n^2+L_{n-1}^2-L_nL_{n-1}+2L_nL_{n-1}\\\\&=L_{n-1}^2+2L_nL_{n-1}-L_n(L_n+L_{n-1})\\\\&=L_{n-1}^2+2L_nL_{n-1}-L_nL_{n+1}\\\\&=L_{n-1}^2+2L_nL_{n-1}+L_n^2-L_n^2-L_nL_{n+1}\\\\&=(L_{n-1}+L_n)^2-L_n(L_n+L_{n+1})\\\\&=L_{n+1}^2-L_nL_{n+2}\qquad\blacksquare\end{align}$$

Answer (score -1):

Some relations about Fibonacci and Lucas numbers:

[image: fibonacci and lucas numbers with applications by thomas koshy]

Comment: Cool! 136 identities! Too bad OP only cares about one, and you don't provide a proof

Comment: I post this formulas because @ X-man asked five Successive questions about relation about Fibonacci number.

Comment: @Wojowu my purpose of this post is that these relation exist and it's proof are in this [book](https://www.amazon.com/Fibonacci-Lucas-Numbers-Applications-Thomas/dp/0471399698).

Comment: This should be a comment in that case, not an answer.

Comment: @Wojowu you right but I dont know how to address my photo in the comment.

Comment: You can upload it somewhere online and provide a link.

Comment: @Wojowu At first, I did in these site [1](http://tinypic.com/) and [2](https://postimage.org/) but unfortunately made error and I dont know why, just because of this I posted it as a answer. By the way, you right.